# How do I expire rows based on a lookup table of expiry times?

Tags: sql, unix-timestamp

If I have two tables:

```
items
    Id VARCHAR(26)
    CreateAt bigint(20)
    Type VARCHAR(26)

expiry
    Id VARCHAR(26)
    Expiry bigint(20)
```

The `items` table contains when the item was created, and what type it is.  Then another table, `expiry`, is a lookup table to say how long certain types should last for.  A query is run every day to make sure that items that have expired are removed.

At the moment this query is written in our app, as programming code:

```
for item in items {
    expiry = expiry.get(item.Type)
    if (currentDate() - expiry.Expiry > item.CreateAt) {
        item.delete()
    }
}
```

This was fine when we only had a few thousand items, but now we have tens of millions it takes a significant amount of time to run.  Is there a way to put this into just an SQL statement?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, they do.  The `Id` field on expiry is the primary key, which is referenced within the `Type` field on `items.

Comment: Wait, but in terms of the tables themselves, they aren't one-to-one.  There will only be one expiry per item, but there may be thousands of items per type.

Comment: MySQL and postgresql are two different RDBMS products with different implementations of SQL. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: @Shadow: it's probably MySQL, because `bigint(20)` is invalid for Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all date values are actually UNIX timestamps, you could write a query such as:

```
SELECT * -- DELETE
FROM items
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM expiry
    WHERE expiry.id = items.type
    AND items.CreateAt + expiry.Expiry < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
)
```

Replace SELECT with DELETE once you're sure that the query selects the correct rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates stored are in seconds since the UNIX epoch, you could use this PostgreSQL query:

```
DELETE FROM items
USING expiry
WHERE items.type = expiry.id
  AND items.createat < EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp) - expiry.expiry;
```

A standard SQL solution that should work anywhere would be

```
DELETE FROM items
WHERE items.createat < EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp)
                       - (SELECT expiry.expiry FROM expiry
                          WHERE expiry.id = items.type);
```

That can be less efficient in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting slow because you do the join between the tables outside the database.

Second slowing aspect is that you delete the items 1 by 1. 
So using the compact delete statements which were provided is the correct solution.

It seems that you are using something like python-sqlalchemy. There the code would be something like:

```
items.delete().\
    where(items.c.type==\
        select([expiry.c.id]).\
             where(currentDate() - expiry.Expiry > item.c.CreateAt ))
```